# Need help setting upper and lower variables with a delta

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi3

This should be very easy but, I just can't wrap my mind around it.  I need to set a variable with the upper or lower limit is reached but, I want to add a delta before setting the variable.

I am building an aquarium controller with a raspberry pi and writing the code in python.  This particular function I want to turn on a heater at 76.0 degrees and turn it off at 78 degrees.

However, I do not want the have the heater bouncing on/off at the limits so, once I turn on the heater I want it to heat to 78 but not turn on again until it gets to the lower limit.

And vice versa, when the lower limit is reached I want it to heat to the higher limit.

The main goal is to not have the gpio pin bounce at the edge of the upper and lower limits.

The gpio pins in the code control a relay to turn the Heater ON/OFF.

Heat On = 1 ....-------------------> 78 degrees

Heat On = 0 ................         76 degrees<------------------

```
def heater(SW_TEMP):
    if SW_TEMP < 76.0:
            heatON = 1
            print "heatON = ", heatON
            GPIO.output(HTR_Ch2, GPIO.LOW)

    elif (SW_TEMP > 78.00):
            heatON = 0
            print "heatON = ", heatON
            GPIO.output(HTR_Ch2, GPIO.HIGH)

    else:
            GPIO.output(HTR_Ch2, GPIO.HIGH)
            heatON = 0
            print "heatON = ", heatON
```

This is a basic function and works however, it will still bounce at the limits as the temperature fluctuates at the limits.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to account for the current state of `heatON`, like:

```
def heater(SW_TEMP):
    if SW_TEMP < 76.0 and not heatON:
            heatON = 1
            print "heatON = ", heatON
            GPIO.output(HTR_Ch2, GPIO.LOW)

    elif SW_TEMP > 78.00 and heatON:
            heatON = 0
            print "heatON = ", heatON
            GPIO.output(HTR_Ch2, GPIO.HIGH)
```